# Shutdown: you must be root to do that

Tags: shutdown, gentoo

How do I allow normal users to shutdown/reboot?

I try to shutdown as my user `el` but get this response:

```
el@voyager ~ $ shutdown now
shutdown: you must be root to do that!
Usage:    shutdown [-akrhPHfFnc] [-t sec] time [warning message]
              -a:      use /etc/shutdown.allow
              -k:      don't really shutdown, only warn.
              -r:      reboot after shutdown.
              -h:      halt after shutdown.
              -P:      halt action is to turn off power.
              -H:      halt action is to just halt.
              -f:      do a 'fast' reboot (skip fsck).
              -F:      Force fsck on reboot.
              -n:      do not go through "init" but go down real fast.
              -c:      cancel a running shutdown.
              -t secs: delay between warning and kill signal.
              ** the "time" argument is mandatory! (try "now") **
```

I want to have my user el be able to shutdown the computer, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

**How to allow normal users to shutdown/reboot in gentoo:**

If you get any of these kinds of errors:

```
shutdown: you must be root to do that!
poweroff: must be superuser.
reboot: must be superuser.
halt: must be superuser.
```

One way to grant users access to superuser only commands to use the `sudo` command:

1. Login as root:

   ```
   su -
   ```
2. Emerge Sudo:

   ```
   emerge app-admin/sudo
   ```
3. Run visudo:

   ```
   visudo
   ```
4. Configure visudo:

   Enter the following into visudo

   ```
   # Replace YourUserName with your user name.
   YourUserName  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
   YourUserName  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/halt
   YourUserName  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
   YourUserName  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
   ```
5. Save visudo file, and exit to normal user access.
6. From user level console, run this command:

   ```
   el@voyager ~ $ sudo shutdown now

   Broadcast message from root@voyager (pts/0) (Sat Sep 21 18:19:56 2013):

   The system is going down to maintenance mode NOW!
   el@voyager ~ $
   ```
7. You may notice that maintenance mode still leaves the fans and power on, yet still gentoo is not running.  You must use the -h flag on shutdown which means halt, Otherwise you're only dropping down into single/maintenance mode.  Consider using 'poweroff' instead.

   ```
   el@voyager ~ $ sudo halt

   Broadcast message from root@voyager (pts/0) (Sat Sep 21 18:26:12 2013):

   The system is going down for system halt NOW!
   ```

The operating system, fans and power are now turned off by the user.

Comment: `halt` is also meant to leave the power on, so `poweroff` is the correct command to use (even though simpler init systems treat them as synonyms).

Comment: `su -` does the same thing as `su - root`—that is, it switches to `root`. Not `su`. There isn't a user called `su` by default (though you _could_ make one…)